# Error when installing GMP on Windows with MinGW

Tags: c++, c, mingw, gmp, msys

I'm on a Windows10 with MinGW offered by [WinLibs](http://winlibs.com/).

I tried to install the GMP library with instructions given by [GMP Install Instruction for Windows Platform](https://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/).

I've done these

1. install MinGW in `C:/mingw64`
2. install MSYS in `C:/MSYS/1.0`
3. download GMP source and extract it into `D:/desktop/gmp-6.2.0`
4. run MSYS and `cd` into `D:/desktop/gmp-6.2.0`
5. run `./configure --prefix="D:/GMP" --disable-static --enable-shared`. This successfully generated a `Makefile`, and show these information in the console:

```
configure: summary of build options:

  Version:           GNU MP 6.2.0
  Host type:         skylake-pc-mingw32
  ABI:               64
  Install prefix:    D:/GMP
  Compiler:          gcc
  Static libraries:  no
  Shared libraries:  yes
```

6. run `make`. The process failed with these error info

```
In file included from set_str.c:57:
set_str.c: In function '__gmpf_set_str':
../gmp-impl.h:4435:29: warning: implicit declaration of function 'localeconv' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 4435 | #define GMP_DECIMAL_POINT  (localeconv()->decimal_point)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~
set_str.c:132:24: note: in expansion of macro 'GMP_DECIMAL_POINT'
  132 |   const char  *point = GMP_DECIMAL_POINT;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../gmp-impl.h:4435:41: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')
 4435 | #define GMP_DECIMAL_POINT  (localeconv()->decimal_point)
      |                                         ^~
set_str.c:132:24: note: in expansion of macro 'GMP_DECIMAL_POINT'
  132 |   const char  *point = GMP_DECIMAL_POINT;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [set_str.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Desktop/gmp-6.2.0/mpf'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Desktop/gmp-6.2.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

7. I was supposed to run `make install` to finish the installation, but I can't since the last step failed.

What's the problem here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Since you already installed MSYS, why not install the GMP package that it provides?

Comment: Otherwise, it looks like a bug somewhere, configure is supposed to detect if localeconv is available, and the code that fails for you is only enabled when configure says yes.

Comment: @Marc Glisse: Does CMP come along with MSYS? I didn't any option during the installation of MSYS.

Comment: https://www.msys2.org/ "MSYS2 is a software distro", it is a package manager. So once installed, you can use it to install other software.

Comment: @Marc Glisse: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it myself. The (deduced) problem was that when I finished installing MSYS, the automatic run of the postinstall script failed and I just ignored it.

After I ran the `postinstall.bat` manually, the GMP library compiled as desired.